# The set of all fractional ideals of $R$ forms a commutative semigroup with a unit element equal to $R$.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I was reading the book "Elementary and Analytic Theory of Algebraic Numbers" by Wladyslaw Narkiewicz and I got stuck in one sentence on page $1$ -----

The set of all fractional ideals of $R$ forms a commutative semigroup with a unit element equal to $R$.

I already proved that it is a semigroup but how is the identity element equal to $R$.

Here, $R$ is a commutative domain and the semigroup operation is product of ideals.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, you should probably tell us what $R$ is (commutative ring with unit?integral domain?) and what the semigroup operation is (product of ideals?). I may not have all the knowledge to answer your question though.

Comment: @6005 I am so sorry, I didn't define the terms. Now I have edited the question.

Comment: Thanks :) Hope you get an answer to your question. Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I$ be any fractional ideal.  Then $R\cdot I\subseteq I$, since by definition $I$ is closed under multiplication by elements of $R$.  Conversely, since $1\in R$, $R\cdot I\supseteq I$.  Thus $R\cdot I=I$.

Comment: How $R.I \subset I$ because by the definition of fractional ideal a fractional ideal of $R$ is an $R$-submodule $I$ of $K$ such that there exists a non-zero $r \in R$ such that $rI \subset R$. Here $I$ is not the usual ideal. $I$ is not closed under multiplication of $R$.

Comment: It's an $R$-submodule of $K$, so by definition it is closed under multiplication by elements of $R$.